# How to replace native android with unity android version in google play

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sharedpreferences

I made a native android application in which I save data in shared preferences, but there is also an in-app purchase opportunity and this is already available in google play. After that, this application was developed in Unity. The goal would be not to develop two versions, so to replace the native Android app with the Unity version, but in such a way that those who previously used the native app and may have even purchased or have data saved they retain their data when they download the Unity version. Is it possible to overwrite the native android app with the same package name with the unity version? Will the data saved by the native android app be somehow accessible from the unity app?

Any idea? How could this work?

Comment: I think you'll need to clarify your question if you want people to help you. At the moment it's a bit too vague for anyone to understand exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, I rewrite it, I hope it is more clarified.